# Xcode Validation Error: this bundle is invalid

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, validation

Hello i want to upload my app to the appstore but i am stuck at the validation.

this is the error message:

[image]

i renamed the application name in the bundle identifier to upload it as a new app in the App Store.I also created a new app in itunesconnect but nothing helps.

Comment: you app's bundle identifier is the same with the one in itunesconnect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you update an existing application with a new version you have to keep the same bundle id. In order to upload the app as an entirely new application, you have to "create a new app" in itunes connect, not add a new version to the existing one.

Also when submitting, version of the app in itunesconnect must be the same as the version of the .ipa you upload. In your screenshot is shown that you are uploading version 1.0 but in itunesconnect you have created an app waiting for version 2.0.

Comment: i created the new application but forgot to set it as reday for upload. now the error is gone, but im still getting a version missmatch warning

Comment: Check the version in itunesconnect and the version in your projectsettings. They should be the same.

Comment: the versionnumber in itunes connect was 1 and in xcode 1.0 . that was the warning. thanks for your help